# ElementTree unique Tags

Tags: python, arrays, lxml

There's a problem with the below code, since the clist array will contain every tag, but I need it to remove any possible duplicates. I can't find a way to get each e.tag results individually, which results in it parsing the entire taglist into the array, one taglist at a time, so it ends up giving you an array consisting of arrays.

Problematic code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('example.xml').getroot()
for nametag in tree.iter('nametag'):
    elems = [e for e in nametag.iter() if len(e.text) > 1]
    clist = []
    for e in elems:
        if not e.tag in clist:
            clist.append(e.tag)
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you want a list of all element names used in the XML document?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear, but if you are looking for all tag names used in a document, something like the following should work.

```
tag_names = set([e.tag for e in tree.xpath('//*')])
```